# I want to update a user Column in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to update a column worker inside job table with the user id of from the bids table

Here is my controller

```
def worker
@bid = Bid.find(params[:id])
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
  @job.update_attributes(worker: @bid.user.id)
  redirect_to projects_path
end
```

end

and i Created a put "worker" in the routes

and here's the link that i'm trying to use

```
<%= link_to 'Assign To Project', worker_path(bid), method: :put%>
```

The Bid and Job are bod in each loop 
The Logic is working in rails console but i think the error is how to get the job id and bid id , it works once but only updating the first job

Comment: What? I don't understand. Please post your models and the error message you get.

Comment: I think he is just confused about the general approach. @Oleander

Comment: I'm not sure, but I just want to point out using `params[:id]` will return the same `id` number. I don't know if you set it up where `Bid` index and `Job` index are supposed to be the same, which is a bit weird, but maybe that is where you're getting stuck?

Comment: @philipyoo The link says 'Assign to Project' which I guess means that something (bid?) needs to be assigned to something else (job?). So I guess the first thing he needs to do is to pass both the job id and the bid id. He currently only passes the bid id.

Comment: @philipyoo yes that's what confuse me , it only assigned to the first job next dosen't work , i didn't know how to get both

Answer (score 2):

Use `button_to` instead of `link_to` if you want to pass several parameters.

> Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL
>   created by the set of options.

```
<%= button_to 'Assign To Project', 
              worker_path(bid), 
              method: :put, 
              params: { bid_id: some_variable } 
%>
```

Comment: This is an update, so I would say that `PUT` makes the most sense. He also needs to pass the `bid_id` in some way.

Comment: Edited. The whole weirdness of it all threw me off a bit so I just put `foo: :bar` as an example of how to pass the params with `button_to`.

Comment: Wouldn't `/jobs/assign/:job_id/:bid_id` make the most sense? Currently it looks like `bid_id` would be optional, which isn't the case. This solution also doesn't have any route validation, so if you pass `:bid_id` as nil, no error would be raise when a 404 should have been shown.

Comment: Not really - what he's doing is just plain strange. If you have a 1-1 relation you would just do a plain PATCH request to the normal `update` route of the `Job` or `Project` or whatever the parent record is. If the bid_id is not valid you should return 422 Bad Entity as the input is bad - not 404.

Comment: However I'm guessing that in reality he wants a one-to-many between Job and Worker where you would use POST `/jobs/:id/assignments` or something similar.

Comment: In REST `id` params just tell you which resource the route acts on, not every required param.  `/jobs/assign/1/5` makes very little sense in that regard since its not very clear what the heck is going on.

Comment: Okay, not sure I agree but sure. I would create a separate action just for assigning so I could have better controll over the assignment like warn when it has been done twice, send out a notification (like an email) or just redirect the user to a specific page. `/jobs/assign/:job_id/:bid_id` is a bit to random, I agree, but `/jobs/assign/job/1/bid/5` would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :jobs do
  put ":bid_id/worker", action: :worker #-> url.com/jobs/:job_id/:bid_id/worker
end

#app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def worker
    @job = Job.find params[:job_id]
    @bid = Bid.find params[:bid_id]
    redirect_to projects_path if @bid.update worker: @job.user 
  end
end
```

The above will you give you the ability to call the following:

```
<%= link_to "Update Worker", jobs_worker_path(job, bid), method: :put %>
```

---

What you're doing should *really* be handled by your [`ActiveRecord Associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

For example, I am expecting you to have a `foreign_key` of [`worker_id`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your `jobs` table; hence if you call `update_attributes worker: @job.user.id`, it's an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

The above code should work for you, however it's still hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's working , sorry for the confusing this is the first time i ask a question here ,

The controller

```
  def worker
    @job = Job.find params[:job_id]
    @bid = Bid.find params[:bid_id]
    if @job.worker.nil?
      redirect_to projects_path if @job.update_attributes worker: @bid.user.id
    else
      redirect_to projects_path , notice: "#{@bid.user.name} assigned on this project"
    end
  end
```

The Link

```
<%= button_to 'Assign To Project',
 job_worker_path(job, bid),
 method: :put,
 params: { bid_id: bid.id }%>
```

The Route

```
  resources :jobs  do
    match 'worker', to: 'jobs#worker', via:[:put]
    resources :bids
  end
```

I was trying to assign bid.user.id to job.worker